# Slack API conversations.setTopic returns '{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_json"}%' error

Tags: curl, slack

I'm testing out the conversations.setTopic from Slack. I had experienced a few errors whilst testing it out. Here is what I've done:

`curl --request POST --url https://slack.com/api/conversations.setTopic --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx' --header 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --data '{“channel”: “xxxxxxxxx”, ”text”: ”this is a test”}'`

This is the error I end up with`{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_json"}%`

I would like to know what am I currently missing here for this to work out? Are there any examples one could show me?

Comment: Made a few changes to the above here:

`curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --data '{"channel": {"id":"xxxxxxxx","topic": {"value":"on-call."}}}' https://slack.com/api/conversations.setTopic`

Comment: I believe topic and channel should just be a string not objects. Have you tried to utilize Slack tester for this method? https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.setTopic/test

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the following by running this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${env.SLACK}' -H 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --data '{"channel":"xxxxxxxx","topic":"On-call: <$presetUsersRaw>"}' https://slack.com/api/conversations.setTopic
```

I needed to remove the "id" bit and the {} bracket within. This was not evident as the documentation found in slack for the Common successful response between chat.postMessage and conversations.setTopic was a little different which threw me off.